# Limit collection view to height of view

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am using a CollectionView to create a list of items in .net maui, and although it loads ok, the CollectionView resizes itself to accommodate the items and exceeds the height the devices screen.  Although it can scroll, it still cuts off the bottom of the list.

Is there a way to limit the area to the screen of the device displaying the CollectionView?  Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DsfrsApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DsfrsApp.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:DsfrsApp.Models">
             
        <StackLayout 
            Padding="8"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Button 
                x:Name="btnFetch"
                Text="Fetch Data"
                Command="{Binding ReloadTaskCommand}"/>

            <CollectionView Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding IncidentCategories}"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                            VerticalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate
                        x:DataType="models:IncidentCategoryModel">
                        <Grid Padding="8">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                        WidthRequest="60" 
                                        HeightRequest="60" 
                                        Fill="WhiteSmoke" 
                                        Stroke="LightGray" 
                                        StrokeThickness="1" 
                                        Margin="0,0,10,0">                           
                            </Rectangle>

                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="Title"/>

                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                Text="{Binding ItemCount}"
                                FontSize="Subtitle" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There's probably an equivalent in Maui but with WPF you'd use a ScrollViewer or Viewbox to constrain/stretch controls to fit a space. Perhaps you'll find something that can do the same.

Comment: That's what I'd hoped for, scrollview seems closest, but it layouts out in a grid rather than a list when embedding the CollectionView in the ScrollView

Comment: you want to be sure the StackLayout is filling the page, and the CV is filling the remainder of the StackLayout.  That's what I would expect in XF and hopefully in MAUI also.  The CV is inherently scrollable so it doesn't need to be contained in another scrollable container

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I have was to move to a ListView which performed exactly as I wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DsfrsApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DsfrsApp.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:DsfrsApp.Models">
             
        <StackLayout 
            Padding="8"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Button 
                    x:Name="btnFetch"
                    Text="Fetch Data"
                    Command="{Binding ReloadTaskCommand}"
                    Margin="8"/>

            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding IncidentCategories}"
                HasUnevenRows="False"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding ReloadTaskCommand}"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding ListRefreshing, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate
                        x:DataType="models:IncidentCategoryModel">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid
                                Padding="8">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle
                                    WidthRequest="60"
                                    HeightRequest="60"
                                    BackgroundColor="lightblue"
                                    Margin="8"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                                   
                               
                                 <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Title"/>

                                 <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Text="{Binding itemCountText}"
                                    FontSize="Subtitle" />

                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in your case would be to replace your StackLayout with Grid like this:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="auto,*"
        Padding="8"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="btnFetch"
            Text="Fetch Data"
            Command="{Binding ReloadTaskCommand}"/>

    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding IncidentCategories}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
            // Item template and such...
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

The row, where you place your collection view has the size set to "*", which does the trick. Setting it to auto should do the problm you describe.